# Intercept traffic above the transport layer

Tags: linux, sockets, intercept

Firstly, I'm relatively new to network programming. I want to intercept and delay HTTP traffic before it gets to the server application. I've delved into libnetfilter_queue which gives me all the information I need to delay suitably, but at too low a level. I can delay traffic there, but unless I accept the IP datagrams almost immediately (so sending them up the stack when I want to delay them), they will get resent (when no ACK arrives), which isn't what I want.

I don't want or need to have to deal with TCP, just the payloads it delivers. So my question is how do I intercept traffic on a particular port before it reaches its destination, but after TCP has acknowledged and checked it?

Thanks

Edit: Hopefully it's obvious from the tag and libnetfilter_queue - this is for Linux

Comment: Will you be wanting to alter the contents of the packets?

Comment: No - just delay and send them on unchanged later.

Comment: The best idea I can come up with right now:
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1024
Then I can read from port 1024, making another connection to actual port 80 for each connection (will this bypass PREROUTING the second time?). Then do what I need to do and write to port 80 when I want to. I'll have to forward responses too though (I don't want to delay them). This sounds like a terrible idea really. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nope, that sounds like a fine plan.

Comment: man 1 strace - this must help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hijack the connections through an HTTP proxy.  Google up a good way to do this if you can't just set HTTP_PROXY on the client, or set up your filter running with the IP and port number of the current server, moving the real server to another IP.

So the actual TCP connections are between the client and you, then from you to the server.  Then you don't have to deal with ACKs, because TCP always sees mission accomplished.

edit: I see the comments on the original already came up with this idea using iptables to redirect the traffic through your transparent proxy process on the same machine.

Comment: Yes this is what I have done and it seems the best way forward

Answer (score 1):

Well I've done what I suggested in my comment, and it works, even if it did feel a long-winded way of doing it.

The (or a) problem is that the web server now, understandably, thinks that every request comes from localhost. Really I would like this delay to be transparent to both client and server (except in time of course!). Is there anything I can do about this?

If not, what are the implications? Each HTTP session happens through a different port - is that enough for them to be separated completely as they should be? Presumably so considering it works when behind a NAT where the address for many sessions is the same.